# Pthread join priority

Tags: pthreads

Let me show you the function first:

```
for (i=0; i<3;i=i+2){
 pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &randtrack, (void *)&rnum_array[i]);
 pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &randtrack, (void *)&rnum_array[i+1]);
 pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
 pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
} 

print final result here;
```

My understanding is after two threads are created, the parent thread will blocked at join(thread1), what is the thread 2 actually come back earlier than thread1? How can make longer thread always stay behind?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. What do you mean by "stay behind"? The order in which you wait for the threads doesn't make any difference. Since you wait for both of them, you won't continue until they both finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `thread2` finishes and `thread1` hasn't, you'll continue waiting until `thread1` finishes. Then you'll wait until `thread2` finishes, which will complete more or less instantaneously. The order in which you wait for the threads won't matter (unless the threads try to interact with each other directly, such as by calling `pthread_kill` or `pthread_join` on each other).

**Update**: Your design is completely wrong for what you're actually trying to do. You want to do this:

1. Create a structure to track the work that needs to be done. It should be protected by a mutex, track how many threads are currently working, and what the next work unit that needs to be assigned is.
2. When you create the threads, have them rung a function that acquires the mutex, grabes the next unit of work, increments the number of threads running, and then does the work.
3. When a thread completes a work unit, it should acquire the mutex, decrement the number of threads running, and see if there's more work to do. When there's no work to do, the thread should terminate.
4. You can now wait for all threads to terminate, which will only happen when all the work is done. This eliminates the loop over the work units.

And please learn a very important general rule -- threads are just the things that get work done. What you want your code to focus on is doing the work, not how it will be done. Try to wait for work to be done, not for threads to be done.

Comment: thanks, In my case, i can only have two threads available to use. There are total 2 iterations for the loop, so is there anyway to let the finished thread continue the second iteration without waiting for the other thread to complete? because thread1 may only take 5 seconds, thread2 may take 10 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, don't wait for the threads at all. Code the threads to keep doing jobs so long as there is work to do and only stop when there is no work to do.

Comment: Sorry, i am new to pthread, so could you explain a little bit more? Also, in this task, i can only use 2 threads, each should be executed twice, Can I move the join out of the loop? But in that case, seems like 4 threads are running. And I have to join these two threads somewhere, because there is a printf function after the for loop, which will print the result made by these two threads in 2 iterations.

Comment: See my update. You're doing it wrong. You're waiting for threads when what you actually want to wait for is work to be completed. You're creating threads when what you actually want to do is assign work to threads.